# Allow RESTful DELETE method in mlab

Tags: javascript, database, mlab

How to set the 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' for [mlab](https://mlab.com/home)

It does not allow `delete` method, when using its RESTful api. There's no instruction on its [documentation](https://docs.mlab.com/data-api/#view-edit-delete-document)

```
var d = new Date()
d.setHours(0,0,0,0)
var yMidnight = d.getTime() - 24 * 1000 * 3600

fetch(url('photo', JSON.stringify({ date: { $lt: yMidnight } })) + '&m=true'), {
  method: 'delete',
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
  }
})
.then(() => {
  console.log('success')
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
})

function url(collection, q) {
  if (q) {
    return `${host}${collection}?apiKey=${apiKey}&q=${q}`
  }
  return `${host}${collection}?apiKey=${apiKey}`
}
```

Comment: Hi, what resource are you trying to use the DELETE method with? The cluster, database, and collection resources do not have the DELETE method. Only the document resources can use the DELETE method. There is no way to change this. If this is an issue, using a MongoDB driver might suit your use-case better.

Comment: Thanks. It's document. I can only use RESTful api.

Comment: Are you having an error deleting a document? The documentation you linked shows that you should be able to do `DELETE /databases/{database}/collections/{collection}/{_id}`.

Comment: I always get 'Error: Method DELETE is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.'

Comment: Can you add the command/code that you are running that generates that response to the question? Please be sure to remove your API key from any code that you share.

Comment: code added.....

Answer (score 1):

The way you delete single and multiple documents is different with the API. The DELETE method only works when you act on a single document resource. So you can make a request like this:

```
DELETE /databases/{database}/collections/{collection}/{_id}
```

This will delete a document with the `_id` specified in the URL. However, the `/databases/{database}/collections/{collection}` endpoint does not have the option of using a DELETE request, even when using the `q` query parameter to return documents.

To delete multiple documents in a collection using the `q` query parameter, you must use a PUT request. See the documentation here: https://docs.mlab.com/data-api/#delete-documents

So your fetch method should look like this:

```
fetch(url('photo', JSON.stringify({ date: { $lt: yMidnight } })) + '&m=true'), {
  method: 'put',
  data: JSON.stringify([]),
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
  }
})
```

This will replace all the documents that match the `q` query parameter with an empty list—that is, deleting them.